# Excluding records if it's a certain type in a running sum

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

Table like this:

```
Description Type    Amount
Record      1       10
Record      2       20
Record      1       5
Record      3       10
```

How do I exclude records of a certain type in my running sum?  So if I exclude Type 3, my running sum becomes:

```
Description Type    Amount  RunningSum
Record      1       10      10
Record      2       20      30
Record      1       5       35
```

I'm using the update local variable technique.  What I have:

```
DECLARE @Amount DECIMAL(18, 4)

SET @Amount = 0

UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET RunningTotal = @Amount
    ,@Amount = @Amount + ISNULL(Amount, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a simple `WHERE` clause, no?

```
WHERE [Type] <> 3;
```

Example (though not sure why you declared your variable as `DECIMAL`):

```
DECLARE @d TABLE
(
  Description CHAR(6), 
  [Type] INT, -- bad column name choice!
  Amount DECIMAL(18,4), 
  RunningTotal DECIMAL(18,4) NULL
);

INSERT @d VALUES
 ('Record',1,10,NULL),
 ('Record',2,20,NULL),
 ('Record',1,5 ,NULL),
 ('Record',3,10,NULL);

DECLARE @rt DECIMAL(18, 4) = 0; -- calling this @Amount is confusing
                                -- it is storing the running total!

UPDATE @d
  SET @rt = RunningTotal = @rt + Amount
  WHERE [Type] <> 3;

SELECT Description, [Type], Amount, RunningTotal FROM @d;
```

Results:

```
Description Type Amount  RunningTotal
----------- ---- ------- ------------
Record      1    10.0000      10.0000
Record      2    20.0000      30.0000
Record      1     5.0000      35.0000
Record      3    10.0000         NULL
```

Also please be aware that this "quirky update" method you are using is not documented, not supported, and could give unpredictable results.

http://sqlperformance.com/running-totals